# SVN tags and branches exploration

Tags: git, svn

in a given SVN repository, **I would like, from a given revision number, to know which tags are potentially affected by that revision**. For that, my idea is to get from this revision the branch it's on, then check which further tags are on this same branch.

I know that, from a given revision number `<rnumber>`, you can get from the log of the revision the information about the branch it affects :

`svn log -r<rnumber> -v`

I can also get the list of the tags and, with the method above, the branches they are on. So I could link revision and tags with some processing of the different outputs.

So before I'm diving into all that, is there an easiest way to do so ? Because in a Git repository you can do that in just one line ...

`git tag -l --contains <rnumber>`

Answer (score 1):

> I can also get the list of the tags and, with the method above, the branches they are on

You can't, in the **strict** sense. In Subversion tags are independent entities at the same level as branches (just nodes in tree), they can't be "on" branches, they can be only "created from"

And you forgot one more sad thing: merges. Revision N in Branch A may be merged to Branch B before tagging B (or not merged), and even worse - it can be a lot of intermediate merges between original branch and source of tagging